# Rerun script for height on window resize?

Tags: jquery, resize, reset

I am setting the height of my elements ".portfolio-set-height", to the highest height for alle those elements (they have different height)  and then I am using this height as min-height for another element. The attached code works for this. But I can not get jquery to rerun the script when the window is resize. Any ideas?

(I have already tried `$(window).resize(function()` with no luck)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var maxHeight = -1;

   $('.portfolio-set-height').each(function() {
     maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
   });

   $('.portfolio-set-height').each(function() {
     $(this).height(maxHeight);
   });
 });


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".work-slider").css("min-height", function(){ return $(".portfolio-set-height").height() });
});
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with your problem ? There are known problem but I won't try to guess which one applies without the code.

Comment: You can put all your functions in ONE document ready-call..

Answer (score 0):

The function you specify inside the $(document).ready is local available. When $(document).ready once is fired, the code is unreachable from outside. You should specify the method outside $(document).ready(). E.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ready1();}); 
$(document).ready(function(){ready2();});
var ready1 = function () { 
    var maxHeight = -1;
      $('.portfolio-set-height').height(''); 
    $('.portfolio-set-height').each(function() { maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height(); }); 
    $('.portfolio-set-height').each(function() { $(this).height(maxHeight); }); 
} 
var ready2 = function () {
    $(".work-slider").css("min-height", function(){ return $(".portfolio-set-height").height() });
}
$(window).resize(function(){ ready1(); ready2(); });
```

Comment: thank you, but I am not sure how to rewrite my code the way you described? (I am very new to jQuery)

Comment: Code in comments is not that good option. Hope this helps.
$(document).ready(ready1); 
    $(document).ready(ready2); 

var ready1 = function () {
 var maxHeight = -1; 
 
   $('.portfolio-set-height').each(function() { 
     maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height(); 
   }); 
 
   $('.portfolio-set-height').each(function() { 
     $(this).height(maxHeight); 
   });
}

var ready2 = function () {
 $(".work-slider").css("min-height", function(){ return $(".portfolio-set-height").height() }); 
}

$(window).resize(function(){ 
    ready1();
 ready2();
}

Comment: Thank you again for your help, but I am getting an error with your code, and it is not working. 
To display the code better you could edit your first answer

Comment: thanks, I can see the alerts are triggered when I resize, but for some reason (when I run the script, without alerts) the height and min-height is not changed on resize?

Comment: I debugged and found your problem. Let me try to explain:
1) On $(document).ready the elements have no height. $(this).height() only gives the computed height. Now with $(this).height(maxHeight), the heights are set.
2) On resize, the heights of the elements will not change, because they are fixed by $(this).height! Only a scrollbar may appear in browser. This means that the first each will return the current height and not the new ones.
Summarize: <div style="height:100px"/> will forever be 100px on every browser resize.

Comment: Okay, makes sence. Sorry for taking so much of your time, but do you have an idea for how to make the min-height change on resize then?

Comment: First you have to set all your height to ''. Than it should work.

Comment: Do you mean in the inline-style? I can not just write height:''; - I tried height:"auto;", but it still doesn't work on resize.

Answer (score -1):

The only function that detect's window resizing is .resize. You need to use the .resize in JQuery: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    // the window has been resized, make changes
});
```

If this is not wokring then you have a proglem with your logic. Post a jsfindle copy paste.

Here's a jsFidel: http://jsfiddle.net/uVkrS/7/

Comment: Did you read the question ? The point about "I have already tried `$(window).resize(function()` with no luck" ?